# Incoming dial-up connection compatibility?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, mac, dial-up

I have a windows 10 machine, a windows xp machine and a mac.

All three of them have working dial-up modems.

I set up my windows 10 pc as an incoming dial up connection server, and the xp machine was successfully able to dial into it and connect.

I also set up the xp  machine as a dial in server and the mac was able to dial into it successfully.

My issue here is the mac will not dial into the windows 10 machine successfully... is there some kind of compatibility issue here? I have my doubts that much would have changed between windows 10 and xp for incoming dialup connections right?

In a nutshell, my question is how can I get my mac to successfully connect to my windows 10 pc?

Any answers are much appreciated.

Comment: What type of modems are in use (win modems ? internal modems with built in serial? external modems?  What chipset?)

Comment: @davidgo I believe the xp machine has an internal winmodem, the windows 10 machine is using an Olitec speed com external modem through a USB serial adapter, and the mac is using an internal modem which is apple official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [external site](http://www.mac-forums.com/os-x-operating-system/8466-mac-dial-windows-rras-tips.html) copy and pasted here:

For those out there experiencing problems with this, trying to connect a Mac running any OS X version to a Windows Server running RRAS, I have some info that may be of help.

I noted online that Mac's prefer to use standard CHAP (MD5) encryption, while CHAP is not enabled on Windows Servers by default. So... I had to get access to the administrator of my Windows Server and ask them to enable the checkbox under Properties of Routing and Remote Access for CHAP. By default Msft selects MS-CHAP authentication, which is different.

Additionally, my Windows dial-in account had to have "passwords stored using reversible encryption" enabled in "Active Directory Users and Computers." Then the password must be manually reset, on either the client or server, n order to store it in Windows using reversible encryption.

Finally, back in Routing and Remote Access on the Windows Server, a Remote Access Policy must be created to "Grant remote access permission" for clients using CHAP authentication for NAS-Port-Type Async (Modem), done through the "Policy conditions" properties window for Remote Access Policies, which is part of Routing and Remote Access on the Windows Server.

Then from your Mac, connect using using DOMAIN\username format, with your password and the correct phone number. After much trial and error and research this finally worked and all of our OS X clients are now able to connect to the Windows RRAS. Whew! Good luck. Chad